# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, xcode7

Before I asked this question I've tried all the available listed solutions.

I'm running old project (from 1 year ago) and I get this error

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-AAShareBubbles
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think there are a problem in linking Pod files, because when I remove the first pod which was AAShareBuble and added it manually, the error moved to the second pod which was AFNetwoking, so I think the problem in Pods configuration or Linking.

```
xCode version: 7.0.1
COCOAPODS: 0.38.2
```

Any one can help ?

Comment: What available listed solutions? Have you checked how the linker is being called and that the `-L` options are the right directories and the `-l` options refer to the correct libraries within those directories?

Comment: cocoapod version and xcode version ?

Comment: xCode version: 7.0.1
COCOAPODS: 0.38.2

Comment: Go to your pods build settings, and set build active architecture to NO and update ur .Make sure you open workspace file, but not xcode project file

Comment: update your podfile!!!

Comment: @Mr.T I already made that, but nothing happened.